# OData cannot provide records count in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using ASP.NET Core Web API and EF Core (code-first) to communicate with a database. I use the following code:

Controller:

```
public class EquipmentController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IQueryable<Equipment>> GetAllEquipmentsList()
    {
        IQueryable<Equipment> list = _sqlServerContext.Equipments
            .Include(x => x.CostCenter)
            .Include(x => x.EquipmentCategory)
            .Include(x => x.equipmentType)
            .AsQueryable();

        return Ok(list);
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services
       .AddControllers()
       .AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().Expand().SetMaxTop(null));
```

I have installed the following version of OData:

[image]

When I use the

```
http://localhost:5000/api/Equipment/GetAllEquipmentsList?$count=true
```

the JSON data is fetched, but there is no count information.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the following codes to `Program.cs`:

```
static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
    builder.EntitySet<Equipment>("Equipments");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()).Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().Expand().SetMaxTop(null));
```